# Spring BOM, commons-logging, Log4j2 and Maven dependency management

Tags: spring, maven, log4j2, apache-commons-logging

I'm building a parent POM for several modules. They are using Spring and Log4j2, so I want to define relevant configuration in  section of parent POM and make use of new Spring BOM feature to avoid a mess with versions of Spring components.

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-maven-bom), this is the correct use of Spring BOM:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    .......
</dependencyManagement>
```

Now, I need to exclude dependency on `commons-logging` from `spring-core`. This is the right way to do it, according to [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-not-using-commons-logging):

```
<dependencyManagement>
    .......
    <!-- Remove JCL from Spring deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add Log4j2 with JCL bridge -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    .......
</dependencyManagement>
```

Removing version number from the definition of `spring-core` dependency causes missing `spring-core` version error during compilation phase (`'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-core:jar is missing`). Effectively, it requires me to re-specify Spring version number - something that Spring BOM was supposed to solve.

Do you know any way to make this work based on BOM version only?

Comment: Did you put it under the dependencyManagement tag? Maybe you should put it under dependencies and not dependencyManagement.

Comment: @Koby Not for a parent POM. Those have to be in `dependencyManagement` - I'm defining dependency versions, not declaring their use.

Comment: Why the exclusion of common-logging under dependencies? It supposed to be under dependencyManagement as well.

Comment: @Tarlog I'm using Log4j2, which has own JCL bridge, so I need to exclude that explicitly. In [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-not-using-commons-logging) they put SLF4J as an example, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but why not in dependencyManagement section? You are configuring the parent pom, right? So you don't have direct dependencies.

Comment: @Tarlog I've updated POM sample to emphasize... Does it look better now?

Comment: Yes, it's better. No idea, sorry. I can only suggest to use properties, so you can have ${spring.version} , just like you are doing with log4j.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the exclusion directly into the bom declaration:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Or you could add commons-logging to dependencyManagement as well, if you want to directly control its version. This is what I did in a recent project:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-logging.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Now it is hard to say whether I tried it and it did not work or I did not thought about it. I'm working on different project in different company now, so i can't really test your suggestion...

Comment: For the first part, it seems you need Maven 3.4 or later [MNG-5600](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5600)

Answer (score 0):

The log4j jcl bridge does not replace the commons-logging jar. Leave it in. It just creates a binding between commons logging and log4j2.